# SQLAlchemy 'prepared' state

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, prepared-statement

I have a problem with SQL Alchemy 0.8.1 on Python 2.7 running on linux box via mod_wsgi.
From time to time it produces the "InvalidRequestError: This session is in 'prepared' state; no further SQL can be emitted within this transaction".

Below is detailed stack trace of the error:

```
...
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2173, in one
    ret = list(self)
                self = <sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query object at 0x7f6f64348dd0>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2216, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
                self = <sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query object at 0x7f6f64348dd0>
             context = <sqlalchemy.orm.query.QueryContext object at 0x7f6f64348d50>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2229, in _execute_and_instances
    close_with_result=True)
        querycontext = <sqlalchemy.orm.query.QueryContext object at 0x7f6f64348d50>
                self = <sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query object at 0x7f6f64348dd0>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2220, in _connection_from_session
    **kw)
                self = <sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query object at 0x7f6f64348dd0>
                  kw = {'clause': , 'close_with_result': True, 'mapper': }

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 798, in connection
    close_with_result=close_with_result)
              mapper = 
              clause = <sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select at 0x7f6f64348d90; Select object>
                self = <sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x7f6f68f6fe50>
                  kw = {}
                bind = Engine(mysql+mysqldb://xxx:yyy@localhost/zzz?charset=utf8)
   close_with_result = True

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 802, in _connection_for_bind
    return self.transaction._connection_for_bind(engine)
              engine = Engine(mysql+mysqldb://xxx:yyy@localhost/zzz?charset=utf8)
                self = <sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x7f6f68f6fe50>
              kwargs = {'close_with_result': True}

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 281, in _connection_for_bind
    self._assert_active()
                bind = Engine(mysql+mysqldb://xxx:yyy@localhost/zzz?charset=utf8)
                self = <sqlalchemy.orm.session.SessionTransaction object at 0x7f6f69be8050>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 181, in _assert_active
    "This session is in 'prepared' state; no further "
         rollback_ok = False
         prepared_ok = False
          closed_msg = 'This transaction is closed'
                self = <sqlalchemy.orm.session.SessionTransaction object at 0x7f6f69be8050>

InvalidRequestError: This session is in 'prepared' state; no further SQL can be emitted within this transaction.
```

This error happens at random - it may take a few days to see it or it might happen after a 5 minutes. I cannot understand what causes this and the biggest problem - I don't understand what this error means. What is 'prepared' state? The documentation has no information on this state. From what I saw it has some relation to two-way transactions but I do not use them in my code. I use Session.query and Session.commit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really guessing here, but I think that maybe you're using threads with the wsgi deployment, and that your session instance is not thread local. You can do this of course, just follow this short tutorial in the official documentation:

[Contextual/Thread-local Sessions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#unitofwork-contextual%20Contextual/Thread-local%20Sessions)

Comment: No, I use several processes with 1 thread per process, this way I basically have several single-threaded instances of my program under mod_wsgi, if I understood everything correctly.

Comment: Your approach is ok but I'm afraid at this point I don't know what's the problem.